# Are targets aware they are targeted by Halfling Jinx?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, racial-traits, halfling

This questions is probably similar to witch hexes and other mind-control spells, but seems different enough to ask.

> Halflings with this racial trait gain the ability to curse another
>   creature with bad luck at will as a standard action. This curse has a
>   range of 30 feet, and you must be able to see the target and have line
>   of effect to it. The target gets a Will saving throw to resist this
>   jinx (DC = 10 + 1/2 your level + your Charisma modifier). If your
>   target makes this saving throw, it is immune to your jinx ability for
>   24 hours. A jinxed creature takes a –1 penalty on all saving throws.
>   This jinx lasts for 24 hours or until you attempt to use your jinx
>   again. A jinx is a supernatural ability, is not mind-affecting, does
>   not allow spell resistance, and can affect any kind of creature not
>   immune to luck effects. This replaces halfling luck.

If my halfling targets someone with the jinx, does his enemy or other observers know they are being jinxed?

Comment: As the [halfling](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/halfling/) alternate race trait **jinx** is a supernatural ability, you may also be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48115/8610) and [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/100993/8610). (And a link to the ability in the question would improve the question!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Observers and the target typically don't know what the [halfling](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/halfling/)'s doing

Unless a [supernatural ability](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities/#TOC-Supernatural-Abilities-Su-)'s description mandates the ability's user take some perceivable action *or* the supernatural ability's description says the ability creates a perceivable effect, there's no indication to observers or to the ability's target that the user is doing *anything* except insofar as the user has apparently done nothing when the user presumably should've been able to do something.

Thus, when a [halfling](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/halfling/) uses the alternate race trait **halfling jinx**—that is itself a [supernatural ability](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Supernatural-Abilities-Su-)—, *neither* onlookers *nor* the creature that must make a saving throw against the halfling's supernatural ability halfling jinx *know* that the halfling's jinxing a creature. In fact, they've no idea *what* that halfling is doing. The halfling's just *there*, staring off into space or whatever.

If the GM rules that supernatural abilities are close enough to spells that the general [Magic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/) rules apply to them (as this GM rules they are), then, if the target [succeeds on the saving throw](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Saving-Throw) against the supernatural ability halfling jinx, the target "feels a hostile force or a tingle, but cannot deduce the exact nature of the attack." Further, the halfling himself knows "if a creature's saving throw succeeds against" the ability halfling jinx.